Is there a way to make a Shapely polygon compatible with BigQuery when an Invalid geography value error occurs
I have a geopandas file with one of the columns being a shapely polgyon. Here is what it looks like.

I tried to upload it to BiQuery using pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df,..., table_schema=[{'name': 'name', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'type', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'population', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'geometry', 'type': 'GEOGRAPHY'}
And got the following error pandas_gbq.exceptions.GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Invalid geography value, error: Polygon's first loop must be shell. It is nested in loop 2; in polygon 1032; in WKB geography; in column 'geometry'; reason: invalid, message: Error while reading data, error message: Invalid geography value, error: Polygon's first loop must be shell. It is nested in loop 2; in polygon 1032; in WKB geography; in column 'geometry'.
I tried checking if the geometry files are valid, and if not, making it valid by df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: make_valid(x) if not explain_validity(x) == 'Valid Geometry' else x) but this didn't seem to help. I also read from here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data that geography types in BigQuery seem to have an orientation but I am not sure how that works.
What can I do to upload this dataframe?

Hi @Winston Li, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.


. I also read from here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data that geography types in BigQuery seem to have an orientation but I am not sure how that works.

You are correct that polygon orientation can be the cause of this error. A polygon has a shell (outer loop) and might have holes (inner loops). The holes should be inside the shell, but what is "inside" and "outside" depends on loop orientation. A shape POLYGON((0 0, 20 0, 10 10, 0 0)) describes a "triangle" polygon but POLYGON((0 0, 10 10, 20 0, 0 0)) describes everything outside of this "triangle", as described in this doc. Thus
SELECT ST_GeogFromText(
     'POLYGON((0 0, 20 0, 10 10, 0 0), (9 4, 10 6, 11 4, 9 4))',
     oriented => TRUE) g

is fine - a triangle with a hole. But
SELECT ST_GeogFromText(
     'POLYGON((0 0, 10 10, 20 0, 0 0), (9 4, 10 6, 11 4, 9 4))',
     oriented => TRUE) g

results in the error ST_GeogFromText failed: Polygon should have only one shell, holes must be inside the shell. Polygon hole 1 is outside of the shell.
Note that I'm passing oriented => TRUE param which forces the same behavior as when loading Geography from Pandas.
To fix this, you can either:

Fix the orientation of the loop in Python. Shapely should be able to do it.
https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.polygon.orient

Upload the Geography as string type, and then convert to Geography using a query with ST_GeogFromText without oriented param.


